# how to map values returned from observable to be used in another observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have the following observable to get list of feed ids from database ( ***i use sugar ORM library***)

```
  public Observable<Set<Long>> getFeedIdsFromDB() {
            return Observable.create(subscriber -> {

                Set<Integer> subscribedFeedIds = new HashSet<>();

               //get feed ids from FeedEntity Table

                for (FeedEntity feed : FeedEntity.listAll(FeedEntity.class)){
                    if (feed.isSubscribed()){
                        subscribedFeedIds.add(feed.getFeedId());
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

this Observable should emits ids to be used for api call in the following:

```
public Observable<StoryCollectionEntity> storyEntityList(final int page) {
        return this.restApi.storyCollection(/* this is feed ids*/ id, page)
                .distinct(storyCollectionEntity -> storyCollectionEntity)
                .doOnNext(saveStoryCollectionToCacheAction)
```

}

i guess i should use some sort of mapping but have no idea how can i implement it.

**EDIT:**
 i did the following modification:

```
// To map feed ids (retrieved from database) to getAllStoryEntityList Observable: 
@Override
    public Observable<StoryCollectionEntity> storyEntityList(final int page) {
        return this.mNewsCache.getFeedIdsFromDB().flatMap(id -> getAllStoryEntityList(page, id));
    }



//call restApi
    public Observable<StoryCollectionEntity> getAllStoryEntityList(final int page, Set<Long> id){
            return this.restApi.storyCollection( id, page)
                    .distinct(storyCollectionEntity -> storyCollectionEntity)
                    .doOnNext(saveStoryCollectionToCacheAction);
        }
```

but api service is never called. something wrong in the mapping.

```
@GET("story")
     Observable<StoryCollectionEntity> storyCollection(
            @Query("feed_ids") Set<Long> feedIds,
            @Query("page") int page);
```

Comment: Did the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Observable created in `getFeedIdsFromDB` isn't emitting any items, so your flatMap and other data transformations never occur because the stream actually has no *data*. You can test this by subscribing directly to the returned Observable and doing something for onNext.

```java
getFeedIdsFromDB().subscribe(feedId -> System.out.println(feedId));
```

You should see that nothing gets printed. When using [`Observable#create`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html), the **onNext** method of `subscriber` in the anonymous class must be manually called with whatever data you wish to pass downstream. The documentation provides sample code for this.

So modifying your Observable to call onNext, we get this:

```java
public Observable<Set<Long>> getFeedIdsFromDB() {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        Set<Integer> feedIds = new HashSet<>();

        // get feed ids from FeedEntity Table
        for (FeedEntity feed : FeedEntity.listAll(FeedEntity.class)){
            feedIds.add(feed.getFeedId());
        }

        // emit a single Set and complete
        if (subscriber.isSubscribed()) {
            subscriber.onNext(feedIds);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
```

Now the `Set` should get passed along. If your goal is to end up with a the emission of a single `StoryCollectionEntity` object after the transformations (and if I'm reading this properly), then your mapping looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the expected output is, but I'll show you a way to do this sort of thing. Maybe you can alter it to fit your use case.

The first step is to allow `id` as a function parameter in `storyEntityList`:

```
public Observable<StoryCollectionEntity> storyEntityList(final int page, int id) {
        return this.restApi.storyCollection(/* this is feed ids*/ id, page)
                .distinct(storyCollectionEntity -> storyCollectionEntity)
                .doOnNext(saveStoryCollectionToCacheAction)
```

Now you can use an `Observable.flatMap`:

```
public Observable<StoryCollectionEntity> getAllStoryEntityList(int page){
    return getFeedIdsFromDB().flatMap(id -> storyEntityList(page, id));
}
```

The naming might be off, but again - I'm not sure what the entities are.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but the getStoryEntityList is never called

Comment: This hints that no ids are returned from the database (empty sets). Is it not the case?

Comment: in fact it returns values   ```` public Observable<Set<Long>> getFeedIdsFromDB() {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            Set<Integer> subscribedFeedIds = new HashSet<>();
            for (FeedEntity feed : FeedEntity.listAll(FeedEntity.class)){
                if (feed.isSubscribed()){
                    subscribedFeedIds.add(feed.getFeedId());
                }
            }
        });
    }  ````